# How do I grep filter a column by word count?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep, cat

I'm trying to design a grep filter in which I have 2 or less words. I'm turning out blank in searching for this answer oddly enough.

Something like:

```
cat someFile.txt | grep count(\w)  < 3
```

Does this functionality even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`, you could match on a pattern that matches exactly 1 or 2 words:

```
grep -E '^\w+(\s+\w+)?$' someFile.txt
```

(Note that this assumes you either don't have any blank lines, or don't want to select those anyway.)

---

With `awk` you could just use the number of fields condition:

```
awk 'NF < 3' someFile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk instead of `grep` for this like this:

```
awk 'NF < 3' file
```

`NF` stands for number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

**Grep**

```
grep -E '^$|^\S+(\s+\S+)?$' file
```

- `\S` is non-space character;
- `?` makes the preceding pattern optional (repeating zero or one times).
- `|` is the alternation operator (the result is *true*, if either of the patterns match);
- `^$` matches empty line;

The same pattern will work with `-P` option (Perl-compatible regular expressions) as well.

---

**GNU Sed**:

```
sed -nr '/^$|^\S+(\s+\S+)?$/ p' file
```

where

- `p` is a command that prints the current pattern space (the current line, in particular), if the preceding pattern matches the line;
- `-n` turns off automatic printing of the pattern space.

The pattern is the same as for the `grep` command above.

---

**Perl**

```
perl -C -F'/\s+/' -ane 'print if scalar @F < 3' < file
```

where

- `-C` enables Unicode support;
- `-F` specifies pattern for `-a` switch (autosplit mode that splits the input into `@F` array);
- `-n` causes the script specified by `-e` to run for each line from the input;
- `scalar @F` returns the number of items in `@F`, i.e. the number of fields.

Comment: As user @Amber said below, the grep statement can skip blanks. Is there a modification to include blanks? And what's the difference between -E and -P?

Comment: @Tom, grep skips blank lines, if the pattern doesn't match blank lines. I've added blank lines with `^$|` in the _sed_ and _grep_ commands. Grep's `-P` adds additional features described in `pcresyntax(3)` and `pcrepattern(3)`, if PCRE is available on the system. By the way, Amber's solution counts only ASCII "words" `\w+`